# When to use list with sum in python

Tags: python-3.x

Here are two examples:

```
sum(list(map(lambda x:x,range(10))))
```

and

```
sum(range(10))
```

The second example does not require a `list()`, but the first one does. Why?

How do I know when is `list()` a necessity? Similarly using `list()` for `min()` and `max()`.

I am running python 3.3.5 with ipython 2.2.0. Here is what I see:
[image]

---

`print(sum)` results in `<built-in function sum>` from python console and `<function sum at 0x7f965257eb00>` from ipythonNotebook. Looks like an issue with hidden imports in notebook.

Comment: `sum(map(lambda x:x, range(10)))` works just fine for me on Python 3.4.2. What version of Python are you running exactly?

Comment: what's the output of `print sum`?

Comment: `from builtins import *` solved the issue by overwriting the `numpy.sum` with `builtins.sum`. Thanks to everybody for your patience and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of the examples require the use of `list`. The `sum` builtin function works with any iterable, so converting the result of `map` to a list isn't necessary.

Just in case, make sure you are indeed using the *builtin* `sum` function. Doing something like `from numpy import *` would override that. (you can simply `print sum` and see what you get).

Comment: Neither of the examples required `list()` when i can from command line. probably this is an issue with some default imports in ipythonNotebook.

Comment: @BiGYaN what's the output of `print sum`?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the 1st one just enforces and expects the output of the map function to be a list because if there are multiple arguments, [map()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) returns a list consisting of tuples containing the corresponding items from all iterables.

But either way base on your example, it would still work.